# Volatility of investment (/w currency hedging)

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, finance, volatility-forecasting

I´ve been trying to compute volatility of investment with currency hedging, and I have a question. Let's take this example. We have our money in a fond copying the S&P500 index, which has 16% volatility. We also know that the current volatility of the dollar toward our currency is 5%. We want to know the volatility of the whole invesment.

Can I compute with the following formula? If so, what is the reason for adding the two deviations instead of multiplying them, considering the volalitity of an index and the currency are mutualy independent (if any correlation exists, it is undefined, at least to my knowledge).

$$\sigma=\sqrt{(16^2)+(5^2)}$$

Comment: I wonder if this would be better suited to the [quant.SE] SE site.

Comment: The short answer is that when A & B are independent, **Var(A + B)** = **Var(A) + Var(B)**.

Comment: @SteveS, but here the currency *multiplies* the asset value, so it is not really $A+B$ but more like $A\cdot B$.

Comment: @RichardHardy, but remember that you're not dealing with asset values--you're dealing with asset *returns*. It's when calculating the returns (i.e. via **ln(V1/V2)**) that the multiplicative relationship becomes additive. If your calculated returns aren't matching up well then it's either because 1.) you're calculating the holding period return (in which case the numbers won't match up perfectly) and/or 2.) the covariance of asset returns and currency returns is not equal to zero (in which case you'll have to add a **2\*cov(retA, retB)** term to your standard deviation formula).